# How to present keyboard and not shrink background image in layout

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a scroll view and inside that there is a layout out. 
Inside that layout I have included a form (basically textfields and textviews)

When in the runtime. if I press on a textfield keyboard will be appear which is tottaly normal. 
But there is a problem background image has been shrinked.

Is there any way to avoid it. Background image shouldn't shrink

Answer (score 14):

you have to change your manifest file

in your activity tag

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

add this.

see this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: thanks for the reply i already tried it. if i apply this. then the scroll view will not work . its a issue for me. coz i have more than 5 fields in my form

Answer (score 1):

We have to set background onto top-level view added to the **Window Manager**

Follow 2 steps to resolve this issue:

1.You have to set background into onCreate() method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_drawable_background);
}
```

2.Remove background from your xml

```
android:background="@drawable/your_drawable_background"
```

**Background Shrink with Scroll View Issue** would be resolved completely.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed it by using

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"

entry inside  tag in manifest file. That should work.